# Redirect nginx 404 to angular route /#/404

Tags: angularjs, redirect, nginx

I have an angular application that uses [angular-ui](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) `$stateProvider` and `$urlRouterProver`.

My angular router redirects to my 404 state accordingly;

```js
$urlRouterProvider.when('', '/').otherwise('404');
$stateProvider.state('404', {
  url: '/404',
  templateUrl: 'partials/404.html',
  controller: 'PageCtrl'
});
```

The final url for this 404 looks like `http://<snip>.com/#/404`. This is working very well, it handles wrong urls matching `/#/whatever/missing/` but it's not covering `/wrong/url/`.

Root 404 is handled by nginx's [error_page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page). I tried a few combinations with `error_page 404`;

```nginx
error_page 404 /#/404;
location = /#/404 {
  root /var/www/<snip>.com/public/;
  internal;
}
```

nginx log output:

```
[error] open() "/var/www/<snip>.com/public/#/404" failed (2: No such file or directory), request: "GET / HTTP/1.1"
```

and it's not redirecting to angular's 404 state (and doesn't change url).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around and reading documentation carefully, we can directly use redirect with [error_page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page). My nginx solution looks like this:

```nginx
location / {
  root  /var/www/<nip>.com/public/;
  error_page 404 =301 http://<snip>.com/#/404;
}
```

I don't like the redirect solution much, but it doesn't seem to break anything with back button so I'm ok with it. :)